# Join items to a new item with many-to-many (n:m)

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, foreign-key-relationship

my rule of business is something like a used car/motobike dealership:

My table "stock" contains cars, so no two of the same products as each automobile belongs to a different owner.

Sometimes the owner has two cars that he wants to sell separately, but also wants to sell them together, eg:

Owner has a car and a motorcycle:

```
+----------------+
| id | Stock     |
+----+-----------+
| 1  | car       |
+----+-----------+
| 2  | motorcycle|
+----+-----------+
```

In case he wants to advertise or sell in two ways, the first would be the car for U$10.000 and motobike for U$5.000

But it also gives the option to sell both together for a lower price (car + bike U$ 12.000), eg:

```
+----+-----------+--------------------+-----------+
| id | id_poster | Stock              | Price     |
+----+-----------+--------------------+-----------+
| 1  | 1         | car                | U$ 10.000 |
+----+-----------+--------------------+-----------+
| 2  | 2         | motorcycle         | U$ 5.000  |
+----+-----------+--------------------+-----------+
| 1  | 3         | car                | U$ 12.000 |
+----+-----------+--------------------+-----------+
| 2  | 3         | motorcycle         | U$ 12.000 |
+----+-----------+--------------------+-----------+
```

This is the best way to do this?

My structure is already doing so (just as I believe to be the best way), I'm using `foreign key` and `n:m`, see my structure:

[image: db]

Comment: "This is the best way to create new items merged from other items (I am NOT referring to query)?"  This question is too ambiguous to answer.  What "new items"?  What "other items"?  What *are* you referring to?  Why is the query important to what you've tried?  All I can say currently is that you've correctly created a many-to-many relationship, and I think most people prefer explicit joins instead of implicit (comma) joins.  Are you trying to display ``posters`` without ``stock`` (an `OUTER JOIN`)?

Comment: @BaconBits I understand and agree with you, thanks for your opinion, just that my question is not directly related query, as I am learning to use "n:m". I edited my question, please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so if I'm understanding the question right, you're wondering if using a junction table is right.  It's still difficult to tell from just your table structures.  The `poster` table just has a price, and the `stock` table just has a title and description.  It's not clear from those fields just what they're supposed to represent or how they're supposed to be used.

If you truly have a many-to-many relationship between `stock` and `poster` entities -- that is, a given `stock` can have 0, 1 or more `poster`, and a `poster` can have 0, 1 or more `stock` -- then you're fine.  A junction table is the best way to represent a true many-to-many relationship.

However, I don't understand why you would want to store a price in `poster` like that.  Why would one price need to be associated with multiple titles and descriptions?  That would mean if you changed it in one spot that it would change for all related `stock`.  Maybe that's what you want (say, if your site were offering both A1 and A0 size posters, or different paper weights with a single, flat price across the site regardless of the poster produced).  However, there just aren't enough fields in your tables currently to see what you're trying to model or accomplish.

So:  Is a junction table the best way to model a many-to-many relationship?  Yes, absolutely.  Are your data entities in a many-to-many relationship?  I have no idea.  There isn't enough information to be able to tell.

A price, in and of itself, may be one-to-one (each item has once price), one-to-many (each item has multiple prices, such as multiple currencies), or -- if you use a price category or type system like with paper sizes -- then each item has multiple price categories, and each price category applies to multiple items.

So, if you can tell me why a `stock` has multiple prices, or why a single `poster` price might apply to multiple `stock`, then I can tell you if using a junction table is correct in your situation.

---

Having seen your edit that includes your business rules, this is exactly the correct structure to use.  One car can be in many postings, and one posting may have many cars.  That's a classic many-to-many, and using a junction table is absolutely correct.

Comment: +1 I understand perfectly what you need is to understand the "business rule", Soon I'll edit the question and let you know.

Comment: I update my answer. could only tell me if this is really correct way? Thanks

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Yes, looking at the business rules, that's a true many-to-many relationship.  What you've got is exactly correct.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear how the examples relate to your diagram because you use different terminology, but I think it's safe to say: If you want to store something like "this entity consists of orange, apple and pear" then the DB design you show is the correct way to do it. You'd have one `poster` entry, and three entries in the `poster_has_stock` pointing to the same `poster` and three elements in `stock`.

Comment: Thanks, but if you download the zip file for download that let you see that this is exactly. I know how it "works" (quote: You'd have one poster entry, and three entries in the poster_has_stock), it really is no doubt. What I need to know is: This is the best structure, or is there a more correct way? Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I posted the example and hinted else. Wait please

Comment: In principle yes, but you wouldn't see that in a table. The whole notion of "the table should return to me" is the issue; tables don't return anything they just sit there, and the result (the second table) would be created from a join between poster_has_stock (for the ids) and stock (for the name). Still: Yes, this is the way to represent such information.

Comment: I update my answer. Could tell me if this is really correct way? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The structure which you're using is best solution in your case, no need to change, just 2 minor changes needed:

```
1. remove 2 indexes: fk_poster_has_stock_stock1_idx and fk_poster_has_stock_poster_idx, because they are primary keys already
2. stock_price field should use decimal data type (more precise)
```

You can read more about Decimal data type [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html)

Comment: 1. Workbench that generated it. But I will follow your recommendation. 2. Apparently decimal and double can cause problems in mathematical operations, so besides changing to decimal, have extensive knowledge of the problems is what will make the difference for me. > Note: I update my answer. +1 for you

Answer (score 1):

I think Your solution is nearly perfect. I think You may add "id" to "poster_has_stock" table. And of course change price type (it was written upper).

But You may consider second option with stock_id in poster table.
WHY?

-There should be no poster with no stock connected to it.

-In most cases there will be offers: one stock <=> one poster
This will allow You also to add as many dependend stocks to poster as You want.

You can also add poster_special_price DECIMAL (9,2) to poster table. 
This will allow You easy to show:
price for stock item.
Special price for stock item with it's dependencies. 
This will be also easier to manage in controller (create, update) - You will be adding poster already with stock, No transactions will be needed during adding new poster.

[image]

Comment: I'll try to understand everything (test) soon return (Today). +1

Comment: I dislike this option.  It's confusing and complicated to select both one-to-many and many-to-many relationships now.  It pretty much necessitates a `UNION ALL` whenever you need to do that, and doesn't add any new ability for the schema to represent any new relationship.  It also makes it much more complicated to change it from a many-to-one to a many-to-many relationship.  I just don't see any benefit.

Answer (score 0):

you may consider a new table that creates a relationship between the stock items such as:

```
stock_component
---------------
parent_stock_id
child_stock_id
child_qty
```

in this way, you can link up many children into one parent in the style of a bill of materials,  then the rest of your links can continue to be simply related to stock_id of the appropriate parent.

Comment: Be more clear please. I think you misunderstand. You did not download my SQLs, right?

Comment: i am describing the way to accomplish the proper normalization for your requirement: If I have the "Product A", "B product" and "product A + product B" When editing the "Product A" must affect the "product A + product B"

Comment: Yes, my table already does this, since the data are in "stock table", the only thing that varies is the price (which should not be a sum), since it can be discount prices.  So your answer is still not answer my question, or you can not be clear enough or you did not understand the question. **My doubt is:** This is the better way to create new items merged from others items?

Comment: I created my tables based http://www.phpknowhow.com/mysql/many-to-many-relationships/ , I edited my question.